# How many numbers in between $1$ and $250$ are not divisible by $2, 3, 5$ or $7$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, divisibility, inclusion-exclusion

How many numbers in between $1$ and $250$ are not divisible by $2, 3, 5$ or $7$? Using the Inclusion Exclusion Principle, I got the answer to be $57$ (i.e. $250-193$), but I'm worried I might have screwed up the arithmetic. Is there a quick and easy way to check whether long calculations like these are right?

Comment: I got the same answer.

Comment: Oh, thank god. Did you have a quick way, or did you have to do it by hand? I suppose I could always write a program.

Comment: I checked with Excel.

Answer (score 4):

I will first consider all integers up to $210$, as it is the L.C.M. of $2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$. The number of integers from $1$ to $210$ which are not divisible by  $2$, $3$, $5$ or $7$ is

$$210-\frac{210}{2}-\frac{210}{3}-\frac{210}{5}-\frac{210}{7}+\frac{210}{6}+\frac{210}{10}+\frac{210}{14}+\frac{210}{15}+\frac{210}{21}+\frac{210}{35}-\frac{210}{30}-\frac{210}{42}-\frac{210}{70}-\frac{210}{105}+\frac{210}{210}$$

which is equal to

$$210\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)=48$$

The integers from $211$ to $250$ can be replaced by $1$ to $40$. I prefer to simply list out all integers satisfying the conditions: $1$, $11$, $13$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, $37$.

So, there are $48+9=57$ such integers.

Comment: Try replacing 210 with 250 and use the greatest integer less than or equal to each quotient.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I suggest you turn your method into an answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Of course I can replace $210$ by $250$ and use the floor function, obtaining $250-\lfloor \frac{250}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{250}{3}\rfloor\dots$. But then I don't have the simplication corresponding to $210\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)$. So please share your idea.

Answer (score 0):

|A∪B∪C∪D|=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|} all singletons−(|A∩B|+|A∩C|+|A∩D|+|B∩C|+|B∩D|+|C∩D|)} all pairs+(|A∩B∩C|+|A∩B∩D|+|A∩C∩D|+|B∩C∩D|)} all triples−|A∩B∩C∩D|} all quadruples

|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|=250/2 + 250/3 + 250/5 + 250/7 = 294

|A∩B|+|A∩C|+|A∩D|+|B∩C|+|B∩D|+|C∩D|= 250/(2*3) + 250/(2*5) + 250/(2*7) + 250/(3*5) + 250/(3*7) + 250/(5*7) = 120

|A∩B∩C|+|A∩B∩D|+|A∩C∩D|+|B∩C∩D|= 250/(2*3*5) + 250/(2*3*7) + 250/(2*5*7) + 250/(3*5*7) = 20

|A∩B∩C∩D| = 1

|A∪B∪C∪D|=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D| − (|A∩B|+|A∩C|+|A∩D|+|B∩C|+|B∩D|+|C∩D|)  +(|A∩B∩C|+|A∩B∩D|+|A∩C∩D|+|B∩C∩D|) − |A∩B∩C∩D|

|A∪B∪C∪D|= 294 - 120 + 20 - 1 = 193
so no not divisible = 250 - 193 = 57 integers

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Learn latex from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).